# Docker bind mount file can't be accessed through Spring Boot web

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker. I tried making a simple Spring Boot Web app that will return the content of a bind mount text file inside a folder called "config". It runs normally outside docker, but the app throws the error `java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /app/config/data.txt (No such file or directory)` when ran through docker.
If checked through the docker container's bash, I can access the folder and file just fine so it is mounted successfully, but for some reason the app just won't read the file.

This is the spring controller where I read the txt:

```
@RestController
public class ReaderController {

    @Value("${mypath}")
    public String mypath;

    @GetMapping("/read")
    public String read() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Reading from txt...");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(mypath);

        String result = "";

        int i;

        while ((i = fr.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)i);
            result += (char)i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the path inside resources/application.yml that would be overriden in docker-compose.yml

```
mypath: C:\spring-volume-practice\config\data.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  spring-volume-practice:
    build: .
    image: spring-volume-practice
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /app/config
    environment:
      - MYPATH = /app/config/data.txt
```

It was mounted successfully but it won't read the text file. I suspect the way I wrote MYPATH variable was wrong but I couldn't think of any other way to write it.

Comment: The spaces in the environment-variable setting are wrong (try `- MYPATH=/app/...` with no spaces around the equals sign) but I'd expect this to result in Spring Boot just not finding the environment-variable override.

Comment: (It does look like there is an extra space in the error message, and this `environment:` formatting problem would cause that.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, you are correct!! It finally worked when I changed it to `MYPATH=/app/`. I didn't know docker compose is very sensitive to white spaces. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As David Maze wrote above, the problem is with the extra space on my environment variable. I changed it into `- MYPATH=/app/...` and it finally worked.